# AChartEngine - Lock an Axis when zooming out

Tags: android, achartengine

I have a Horizontal Bar Graph generated by AChartEngine. However, I'm having an issue.

When the application first starts, the Y-Axis Minimum Value starts at 0, so all bars are visible as shown in this photo:

[image: This is the start of the application]

However, when the user presses the zoom out button, the whole graph zooms out, and my bars float as seen in this photo:

[image: When zoomed out]

As seen, the X-Axis moves, and the origin (0,0) is no longer at the original position.

So my question is: **Is it possible to lock an axis in such a way that when you zoom out, the bars are still aligned at the Y-Axis?**

Here is my code:

```
public class BarGraph {

    public Intent getIntent(Context context) {

        int y[] = { 25, 10, 15, 20 };

        CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Bar1");
        for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            series.add("Bar" + (i + 1), y[i]);
        }

        // collection of series under one object, there could any number of series
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataSet = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset(); 
        dataSet.addSeries(series.toXYSeries()); 

        // customization of the chart

        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer(); // one renderer for
                                                            // one series
        renderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 5.5d);
        renderer.setLineWidth((float) 10.5d);

        //collection of multiple vales for one renderer or series
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(); 

        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        mRenderer.setChartTitle("Demo Graph");
        // mRenderer.setXTitle("xValues");
        mRenderer.setYTitle("Rupee");
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        mRenderer.setShowLegend(true);
        mRenderer.setShowGridX(true); // this will show the grid in graph
        mRenderer.setShowGridY(true);
        // mRenderer.setAntialiasing(true);
        mRenderer.setBarSpacing(.5); // adding spacing between the line or
                                        // stacks
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMax(5);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMax(50);
        //
        mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(1, "Income");
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(2, "Saving");
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(3, "Expenditure");
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(4, "NetIncome");


        mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false); // will fix the chart position
        mRenderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);

        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, dataSet,
                mRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);

        return intent;
    }
}
```

Also, how do you adjust the font size and space allocated for the Axis Labels?

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tweak the zoom behavior this way:

```
mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, false);
```

For the labels size, use:

```
mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize();
```

For the padding, use:

```
mRenderer.setXLabelsPadding();
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I have a followup, how do you remove the numbers in the X-Axis? I just noticed it now and the numbers (0-5) are under the bar labels.

Comment: mRenderer.setXLabels(0);